# Promise failing because of 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, graphql, relay

I am getting this error.

Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

I hope the rest of my code does what it should, but somehow my promise does not work. What am i doing wrong?

```
// @flow
import { commitMutation, graphql } from 'react-relay';

const mutation = graphql`
    mutation CopyArticleMutation($input: CopyArticleInput!) {
        copyArticle(input: $input) {
            article{
                rowId
            }
        }
    }
`;

export default (baseId: string, environment: any) => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commitMutation(environment, {
            mutation,
            variables: {
                input: {
                    baseId,
                },
            },
            onCompleted: resolve,
            onError: reject,
        });
    });
};
```

I then use this like so:

```
createArticleFromTemplate = (templateArticle: Object) => {
        if (!templateArticle.isTemplate) {
            return null;
        }

        if (templateArticle.id !== 'undefined' && templateArticle) {
            CopyArticleMutation(templateArticle.id, this.props.relay.environment).then(({ copyArticle }) => {
                console.log(copyArticle);
            });
        }
    };
```

I am sure this is a trivial error. Help is appreciated anyway.

Comment: Sorry. Had the wrong code for a couple of seconds...

Comment: `CopyArticleMutation` doesnt return anything - hence is undefined

Comment: would `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... `fix it?

Comment: Possibly, but it could also be a [Promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns)

Comment: hmm it works now, but it returns `null`. I mean the `console.log(copyArticle)` ...

Comment: anyone want to answer it and gain easy points? @jamiec you actually got it right with the missing return soooo....